# Jasmine SpyOn subscription not executing next call

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am trying to spy on my subscription, but I cannot seem to figure out how I can do it. The method itself looks like this:

**list.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ListService {

  public constructor(
    private readonly queryBuilderService: QueryBuilderService
  ) {}

  public paginate() {
    this.paginator = this.queryBuilderService
      .table('a') // Returns instance of QueryBuilder.ts
      .firstPage();
 
    this.paginator.$pagination.subscribe(() => {
      window.scroll(0, 0);
    });
    return this.paginator;
  }
}
```

The `firstPage()` method executes the query and returns the current object which then we listen for changes with the `$pagination` Observable they look like this:

**QueryBuilder.ts** - Note: this is not a service.

```
export class QueryBuilder {
  private readonly paginationBehavior: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public $pagination = this.paginationBehavior.asObservable();

  public firstPage() {
    // Do stuff then execute query
    return this;
  }
}
```

So now to create my test case, I create a spy on `firstPage()` and return an instance of `QueryBuilder`, which calls `next()`. I wait for a short period but it never executes the window spy that I create.

```
  it('should paginate', fakeAsync(() => {
    const httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    const spy = spyOn(window, 'scroll');

    const queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.prototype;
    const queryBuilderInstance = new QueryBuilder(new GraphQLClientService(httpClient));

    spyOn(queryBuilder, 'firstPage').and.callFake(() => {
      queryBuilderInstance['paginationBehavior'].next({
        count: 1,
        isFirstPage: true,
        isLastPage: false,
        page: 1,
        pages: 1,
        results: [],
        total: 1
      });
      return queryBuilderInstance;
    });

    service.paginate();
    tick(1000);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix that seemed to work for me was to put a `setTimeout` within the `firstPage` spy to mimic a network request, and then subscribe to the response of the `paginate()` method.

```
  it('should paginate', async(inject([HttpClient], (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
    const spy = spyOn(window, 'scroll');

    const queryBuilderInstance = new QueryBuilder(new GraphQLClientService(httpClient));

    spyOn(QueryBuilder.prototype, 'firstPage').and.callFake(() => {
      setTimeout(() =>
        queryBuilderInstance['paginationBehavior'].next({
          count: 1,
          isFirstPage: true,
          isLastPage: false,
          page: 1,
          pages: 1,
          results: [],
          total: 1
        })
        , 10);
      return queryBuilderInstance;
    });

    service.paginate().$pagination.subscribe(() => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  })));
```

Answer (score 0):

when we wrote tests in `AngularJS` and `stub promises` using `SpyOn` we did something like this:

```js
spyOn(someService,'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
```

The code above is completely valid — unlike `observables`, `promises` are always asynchronous. But How to test `Observables`?
Using **`jasmine-marbles`** is one of the soultions.

For more information about `observables` test see these articles:

[Testing Observables in Angular](https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329)

[How to test Observables](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad)

Comment: I am writing the test on a service not a component, will that have any affect?

Comment: It's the matter of testing asyn behavior of `Observables`. it's not important that it is testing on a service or component I think. the matter is tetsing `Observables` which 'jasmine-marbles' can be a solution

Comment: You are using `fixture.detectChanges();` I think that is only available on a component.

Comment: Read the first article which include a wrong test scenario. I think it can help you ;)

Comment: Yea, the example is for component testing, but just an example for introducing `marbels`